# getting special characters in select option in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am getting special characters in select option for chrome only.

```
<div class="ius-text-input-container first-name-input name-input">
  <div class="styled-select expiry-period complete">
    <select name="billingState" id="billingState" placeholder="state" style="border-color: rgb(158, 158, 158);">
<option value="State">State</option>
<option value="AK">AK</option>
<option value="AL">AL</option>
<option value="AR">AR</option>
<option value="AS">AS</option>
<option value="AZ">AZ</option>
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="CO">CO</option>
<option value="CT">CT</option>
<option value="DC">DC</option>
<option value="DE">DE</option>
<option value="FL">FL</option>
<option value="FM">FM</option>
<option value="GA">GA</option>
<option value="GU">GU</option>
<option value="HI">HI</option>
<option value="IA">IA</option>
<option value="ID">ID</option>
<option value="IL">IL</option>
<option value="IN">IN</option>
<option value="KS">KS</option>
<option value="KY">KY</option>
<option value="LA">LA</option>
<option value="MA">MA</option>
<option value="MD">MD</option>
<option value="ME">ME</option>
<option value="MI">MI</option>
<option value="MN">MN</option>
<option value="MO">MO</option>
<option value="MP">MP</option>
<option value="MS">MS</option>
<option value="MT">MT</option>
<option value="NC">NC</option>
<option value="ND">ND</option>
<option value="NE">NE</option>
<option value="NH">NH</option>
<option value="WV">WV</option>
<option value="WY">WY</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: May we see some code, please?

Comment: Is this hardcoded HTML or something is generating it ?

In any case, it's most likely to be a poor encoding. Answering my question will help debug the problem.